# Clear and reset form input fields

Tags: reactjs

I have a form containing various input fields and two buttons; one for submitting and one for cancelling.

```
<form id="create-course-form">
  <input type="text" name="course_Name" ref="fieldName">
  <input type="text" name="course_org" ref="fieldOrg">
  <input type="text" name="course_Number" ref="fieldNum">

  <input type="submit" name="saveCourse" value="Create">
  <input type="button" name="cancelCourse" value="cancel" onClick={this.cancelCourse}>
</form>
```

What I want is to empty all inputs when the cancel button is clicked. So far I've managed to do this by using each input's **ref** prop.

```
cancelCourse(){
  this.refs.fieldName.value="";
  this.refs.fieldorg.value="";
  this.refs.fieldNum.value="";
}
```

However, I want to empty the input fields without having to empty each one seperately. I want something similar to this (jQuery): `$('#create-course-form input[type=text]').val('');`

Comment: Use managed input.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The answer here depends on whether or not your inputs are *controlled* or *uncontrolled*. If you are unsure or need more info on this, check out what the official docs say about [**controlled components**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and [**uncontrolled components**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). *Thanks **@Dan-Esparza** for providing the links.*

*Also, please note that [**using string literals in `ref` is deprecated**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). Use the standard callback method instead.*

---

#### Clearing a form with uncontrolled fields

You can clear the entire form rather than each form field individually.

```
cancelCourse = () => { 
  document.getElementById("create-course-form").reset();
}

render() {
  return (
    <form id="create-course-form">
      <input />
      <input />
      ...
      <input />
    </form>
  );
}
```

If your form didn't have an `id` attribute you could use a `ref` as well:

```
cancelCourse = () => { 
  this.myFormRef.reset();
}

render() {
  return (
    <form ref={(el) => this.myFormRef = el;}>
      <input />
      <input />
      ...
      <input />
    </form>
  );
}
```

---

#### Clearing a form with controlled fields

If you are using controlled form fields, you may have to explicitly reset each component inside your form, depending on how your values are stored in the state.

If they are declared individually, you need to reset each one explicitly:

```
cancelCourse = () => { 
  this.setState({
    inputVal_1: "",
    inputVal_2: "",
    ...
    inputVal_n: "",
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <input value={this.state.inputVal_1} onChange={this.handleInput1Change}>
    <input value={this.state.inputVal_2} onChange={this.handleInput2Change}>
    ...
    <input value={this.state.inputVal_n} onChange={this.handleInputnChange}>
  );
}
```

**Demo below:**

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      inputVal_1: "",
      inputVal_2: "",
      inputVal_3: "",
      inputVal_4: "",
      inputVal_5: "",
      inputVal_6: "",
      inputVal_7: "",
      inputVal_8: "",
      inputVal_9: "",
      inputVal_10: ""
    };
  }
  
  handleInput1Change = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputVal_1: e.target.value});
  }
  
  handleInput2Change = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputVal_2: e.target.value});
  }
  
  handleInput3Change = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputVal_3: e.target.value});
  }
  
  handleInput4Change = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputVal_4: e.target.value});
  }
  
  handleInput5Change = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputVal_5: e.target.value});
  }
  
  handleInput6Change = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputVal_6: e.target.value});
  }
  
  handleInput7Change = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputVal_7: e.target.value});
  }
  
  handleInput8Change = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputVal_8: e.target.value});
  }
  
  handleInput9Change = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputVal_9: e.target.value});
  }
  
  handleInput10Change = (e) => {
    this.setState({inputVal_10: e.target.value});
  }
  
  cancelCourse = () => { 
    this.setState({
      inputVal_1: "",
      inputVal_2: "",
      inputVal_3: "",
      inputVal_4: "",
      inputVal_5: "",
      inputVal_6: "",
      inputVal_7: "",
      inputVal_8: "",
      inputVal_9: "",
      inputVal_10: ""
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input value={this.state.inputVal_1} onChange={this.handleInput1Change} />
        <input value={this.state.inputVal_2} onChange={this.handleInput2Change} />
        <input value={this.state.inputVal_3} onChange={this.handleInput3Change} />
        <input value={this.state.inputVal_4} onChange={this.handleInput4Change} />
        <input value={this.state.inputVal_5} onChange={this.handleInput5Change} />
        <input value={this.state.inputVal_6} onChange={this.handleInput6Change} />
        <input value={this.state.inputVal_7} onChange={this.handleInput7Change} />
        <input value={this.state.inputVal_8} onChange={this.handleInput8Change} />
        <input value={this.state.inputVal_9} onChange={this.handleInput9Change} />
        <input value={this.state.inputVal_10} onChange={this.handleInput10Change} />
        <input type="submit" name="saveCourse" value="Create" />
        <input type="button" name="cancelCourse" value="cancel" onClick={this.cancelCourse} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

There is a cleaner way to do this though. Rather than having `n` state properties and `n` event handlers, one for each input, with some clever coding we can reduce the code dramatically.

In the constructor we just declare an empty object, which will be used to hold input values. We use only one input handler and pass it the index of the input element we want to change the value of. This means that the value of an individual input is generated the moment we start typing into it.

To reset the form, we only need to set our input object back to being empty again.

The input value is `this.state.inputVal[i]`. If `i` doesn't exist (we haven't typed anything yet into that input) we want the value to be an empty string (instead of null).

```
cancelCourse = () => { 
  this.setState({inputVal: {}});
}

render() {
  return (
    <form>
      {[...Array(n)].map(
        (item, i) => <input value={this.state.inputVal[i] || ""} onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this, i)} />
      )}
    </form>
  );
}
```

**Demo below:**

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      inputVal: {}
    };
  }
  
  handleInputChange = (idx, {target}) => {
    this.setState(({inputVal}) => {
      inputVal[idx] = target.value;
      return inputVal;
    });
  }
  
  cancelCourse = () => { 
    this.setState({inputVal: {}});
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <form>
        {[...Array(10)].map(  //create an array with a length of 10
          (item, i) => <input value={this.state.inputVal[i] || ""} onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this, i)} />  //bind the index to the input handler
        )}
        <input type="submit" name="saveCourse" value="Create" />
        <input type="button" name="cancelCourse" value="cancel" onClick={this.cancelCourse} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm using uncontrolled fileds so i user reset() function, it's working like a charm now

Comment: For future readers wondering what 'controlled' vs 'uncontrolled fields are, check out the [docs on the React homepage for working with forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

Comment: @Chris  what's the best practice for clearing a form using controlled components? I was told "Setting state of an input to '' is considered an anti-pattern.", they suggested using this on componentWillUnmount but with caution.  And as an alternative  to use document.getElementById("someID").value = '' so I got lost ? any ideas

Comment: @yokodev, not quite following. Please consider posting a new question and post more info there. Also state that you've read this question but that you still don't understand X and Y. Also ping me with a link to it and I'll check it out.

Comment: I think that clearing the form with a ref and the reset() method (second option) is the most convenient and performant, unless you need controlled fields (third option).

Comment: how to do this with hooks ?

Comment: @UsmanI almost the same way. Just remove `this` from `this.handleInput` and make `cancelCourse` a constant

Answer (score 119):

Very easy:

```js
handleSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.reset();
}
```

```
// If using class component
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
  ...
</form>
```

```
// If using function component
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: I am getting this error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
```
Instead of form I have another component where I am calling handleSubmit(). I am using react js

Comment: try to do ```e = e || window.event``` before ```e.preventDefault()``` for handling ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined```  @Amnahkhatun

Answer (score 21):

Using `event.target.reset()` only works for uncontrolled components, which is not recommended. For controlled components you would do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class MyForm extends Component {
  initialState = { name: '' }

  state = this.initialState

  handleFormReset = () => {
    this.setState(() => this.initialState)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <form onReset={this.handleFormReset}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter name"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={this.handleInputOnChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
          />
          <input
            type="reset"
            value="Reset"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ContactAdd.propTypes = {}

export default MyForm
```

Comment: +1 for your use of `initialState`, great if you're resetting a form in several places (a reset button but also after submitting, for example)

Answer (score 11):

You can also do it by targeting the current input, with `anything.target.reset()` . This is the most easiest way!

```
handleSubmit(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 e.target.reset();
}

<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's an update to Chris's answer above, using modern [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Same high level idea; your form can be either a [Controlled or Uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

### Uncontrolled components:

Uncontrolled components leave state management up to the browser. That means you have to ask the browser to reset the form inputs. To do that, capture the form element as a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), and then call the `submit()` method on that element.

```
export default function Form() {
  const ref = React.useRef();

  function reset(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ref.current.reset();
  }

  return (
    <form ref={ref}>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" />
      <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

### Controlled components:

With a controlled component, you manage the state in React. That means you have to create the initial state, and update it every time an input changes. In this world, resetting the form is just a matter of setting the form state back to its initial state.

```
export default function Form() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ email: "", message: "" });

  function reset(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    setState({ email: "", message: "" });
  }

  return (
    <form className="Form">
      <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
      <input
        id="email"
        type="email"
        name="email"
        value={state.email}
        onChange={(ev) => {
          setState({ ...state, email: ev.target.value });
        }}
      />
      <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
      <textarea
        id="message"
        name="message"
        value={state.message}
        onChange={(ev) => {
          setState({ ...state, message: ev.target.value });
        }}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Full example at https://codesandbox.io/s/reactformreset-10cjn3

Answer (score 2):

Following code should reset the form in one click.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleSubmit(e){
    this.refs.form.reset();
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
         <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name!" ref='firstName'/><br/<br/>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name!" ref='lastName'/><br/><br/>
                <button type="submit" >submit</button>
            </form>
       </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, but I've already covered this in my answer. Also, using string literals for `refs` is deprecated. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs

Comment: @Chris, yeah that true as `refs` difficult to test especially when using `shallow`

Answer (score 2):

When the form is submitted, the 'event' will be passed as an argument to the `handleSubmit` method, and if that you can access the `<form>` element by typing `event.target`. then you just need to reset the form using .reset() form method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

```
  handleSubmit = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    ....

    event.target.reset()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor='movieTitle'>Title</label>
          <input name='movieTitle' id='movieTitle' type='text' />

          <input type='submit' value='Find Movie Info' />
        </form>
      </>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To clear your form, admitted that your form's elements values are saved in your state, you can map through your state like that :

```
  // clear all your form
  Object.keys(this.state).map((key, index) => {
      this.setState({[key] : ""});
   });
```

If your form is among other fields, you can simply insert them in a particular field of the state like that:

```
 state={ 
        form: {
        name:"",
        email:""}
      }

      // handle set in nested objects
      handleChange = (e) =>{ 
        e.preventDefault(); 

        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        newState.form[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(newState);
      }

      // submit and clear state in nested object 
      onSubmit = (e) =>{ 
        e.preventDefault(); 

       var form =   Object.assign({}, this.state.form);
       Object.keys(form).map((key, index) => {
          form[key] = "" ;
        });

       this.setState({form})
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

**This one works best to reset the form.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputVal: props.inputValue
    }
    // preserve the initial state in a new object
    this.baseState = this.state ///>>>>>>>>> note this one.
  }
  resetForm = () => {
    this.setState(this.baseState) ///>>>>>>>>> note this one.
  }
  submitForm = () => {
    // submit the form logic
  }
  updateInput = val => this.setState({ inputVal: val })
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          onChange={this.updateInput}
          type="text
          value={this.state.inputVal} />
        <button
          onClick={this.resetForm}
          type="button">Cancel</button>
        <button
          onClick={this.submitForm}
          type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is doing it regularly with just HTML and using the button type "reset" there is no need to mess with anything in react at all, no state, no nothing.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function HowReactWorks() {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <div>
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password" />
        </div>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HowReactWorks
```

- edited for the people that don't know how to include HTML in react

Comment: Please try to answer the questions as they are asked, giving answers that won’t help in the given situation isn’t helpful. The question clearly shows they are already using React, so giving an answer that won’t work in a React world isn’t a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that worked for me, in the case of parent component triggering reset of child controlled input components:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [reset, setReset] = useState()

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    //do your stuff
    setReset(Date.now()) // pass some value to trigger update
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <ChildInputComponent reset={reset} />
      <ChildInputComponent reset={reset} />
    </form>
  )
}

const ChildInputComponent = ({reset}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue('')
  }, [reset])

  return <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

React also allows us to set key.
Setting different key on specific event will make your form to its initial state.

```
const [initialKey, setInitialKey] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (actionData) setInitialKey((prevState) => ++prevState);
  }, [actionData]);
retrun <FormComponent key={initialKey} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant. But when I had similar issue this is how I resolved it.

Where you need to clear an uncontrolled form you simply do this after submission.

```
this.<ref-name-goes-here>.setState({value: ''});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.formRef = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      loading: false,
      eror: null
    }
  }

  reset = () => {
    this.formRef.current.reset()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input type="email" name="" id=""/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <button onClick={()=>this.reset()}>Reset</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/*
See ***newState*** and use of it in ***eventSubmit()*** for **resetting** all the state.
I have tested it is working for me. Please let me know for mistakes
*/

```
import React from 'react';
    
    const newState = {
        fullname: '',
        email: ''
    }
    
    class Form extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                fullname: ' ',
                email: ' '
            }
    
            this.eventChange = this
                .eventChange
                .bind(this);
            this.eventSubmit = this
                .eventSubmit
                .bind(this);
        }
        eventChange(event) {
            const target = event.target;
            const value = target.type === 'checkbox'
                ? target.type
                : target.value;
            const name = target.name;
    
            this.setState({[name]: value})
        }
    
        eventSubmit(event) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(this.state))
            event.preventDefault();
            this.setState({...newState});
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <form className="row mt-5" onSubmit={this.eventSubmit}>
                        <label className="col-md-12">
                            Full Name
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="fullname"
                                id="fullname"
                                value={this.state.fullname}
                                onChange={this.eventChange}/>
                        </label>
                        <label className="col-md-12">
                            email
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="email"
                                id="email"
                                value={this.state.value}
                                onChange={this.eventChange}/>
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you declared

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);
```

As multiple parameters. You can actually reset the items using this syntax:

```
setInputs([]);
```

Just in case, this how you define handleChange.

You can use this form or any ways you want.

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        const email = event.target.email;
        const message = event.target.message;
        const value = event.target.value;
        setInputs(values => ({...values, [name]: value, [email]: value, [message]: value}))
    }
```

You can use this form as an example.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <div className="fields">
        <div className="field half">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input value={inputs.name || ''} type="text" name="name" id="nameId" onChange={handleChange} maxLength="30" />
        </div>
        <div className="field half">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input value={inputs.email || ''} type="text" name="email" id="emailId" onChange={handleChange} maxLength="40"/>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea value={inputs.message || ''} name="message" id="messageId" rows="6" onChange={handleChange} maxLength="400" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul className="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" className="primary" /></li>
        <li><input onClick={resetDetails} type="reset" value="Clear" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

This is just one of many ways to declare forms. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
  const onReset = () => {
    form.resetFields();
  };
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

### Function to reset all data fields to their initial values

```js
function resetAll() {
  // Set data fields to their initial values
  setData({
    name: "", // Reset name field to empty string
    email: "", // Reset email field to empty string
    password: "", // Reset password field to empty string
    about: "", // Reset about field to empty string
  });
}
```

#### And here's the button component calling the resetAll function:

```html
<button onClick={resetAll}>
  Reset
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
state={ 
  name:"",
  email:""
}

handalSubmit = () => {
  after api call 
  let resetFrom = {}
  fetch('url')
  .then(function(response) {
    if(response.success){
       resetFrom{
          name:"",
          email:""
      }
    }
  })
  this.setState({...resetFrom})
}
```

Comment: If possible, it's better to include some explanation along with your code, to describe how this answers the question, and why it's different from the several other answers already here.

Answer (score -1):

**You can use this method as well**

```
const resetData = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
settitle("");
setdate("");
};
    
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => settitle(e.target.value)} value={title} />
    
<input type="date" onChange={(e) => setdate(e.target.value)} value={date} />
    
<button onClick={resetData}>Reset Data</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not use HTML-controlled items such as `<input type="reset">`

Comment: Use as a commment