# Clear Select component after an option is selected in Ant Design and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using just the Select component of Ant Design. I need to select an option and add it to a list, but after selecting the option, I would like to clean the select input.

```
// Receiving these props
const {
  fields,
  onAdd,
  selected,
} = this.props;
```

In the code below, when the user select an option, it will call the onAdd method in order to add the selected option to a list in its parent.

```
<Select
  showSearch
  placeholder="Select a field"
  onSelect={(value) => {
    const optionSelected = fields.filter(field => field.id === value)[0];
    onAdd(optionSelected);
  }
  optionFilterProp="children"
  filterOption={(input, option) => (
    option.props.children.toLowerCase()
      .indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
  )}
>
  {
    fields.map(field => (
      <Option
        key={field.id}
        value={field.id}
        disabled={selected.some(item => item.id === field.id)}
      >
        {field.name}
      </Option>
    ))
  }
</Select>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I solved my "problem" just setting null to the value property.

```
<Select
  value={null}
  showSearch
  placeholder="Select a field"
  onSelect={(value) => {
    const optionSelected = fields.filter(field => field.id === value)[0];
    onAdd(optionSelected);
  }
  optionFilterProp="children"
  filterOption={(input, option) => (
  option.props.children.toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
  )}
>
  {
    fields.map(field => (
      <Option
        key={field.id}
        value={field.id}
        disabled={selected.some(item => item.id === field.id)}
      >
        {field.name}
      </Option>
    ))
  }
</Select>
```

I'm using the select almost as a button, to select and direct add an item on a list. I don't know if this an anti-pattern.

Let me know if anyone has a different approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. But this will not work inside <Form.Item> tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ref="someRef"` in your JSX template and use it in your `onSelect` logic.

Additional examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922508/clear-and-reset-form-input-fields/43922523).

Comment: Hi bbuzze! It was simpler than I thought. I just set the property value to null.