# How to reset input field from useRef in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text input. If I click on a specific button in the page, I want to reset the value of the input. Here is my code:

```
const inputRef = useRef()

const handleClick= () => {
 inputRef.current.value.reset();
 return "hello world"
}

return (
<>
<input type="text" ref={inputRef}/>
<button onClick={()=> handleClick}>delete all</button>
</>
)
```

It doesn't work. How to fix this?

Comment: You should be using state for your inputs, so just reset the state.  With react you should avoid direct Dom access as much as possible.

Comment: Ok, I've just reseted the input value with my state. I'd be curious to know how to do it though.

Comment: Never mutate state! Just reset state with something like this.. `.setState({ input: "" })`

Comment: Yes this is what I've done. input value={query}/> and then setQuery("")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear and reset form input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922508/clear-and-reset-form-input-fields)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can clear the text input field by setting its value to an empty string. You can do that like this `inputref.current.value = ""` if you want to use uncontrolled inputs.

However, if you want to use controlled inputs you can create a state variable to track the value of the input field. For example,

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('')

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => setText('')}>delete all</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-platform-dcb0b?file=/src/App.js) with both implementation.

Answer (score 24):

`reset` is available on `form` element.
You can wrap your input with a form, and trigger `reset` on it.

```js
const {useRef} = React;
const App = () => {
  const formRef = useRef();

  const handleClick = () => {
    formRef.current.reset();
  };

  return (
    <form ref={formRef}>
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="password" />
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button onClick={handleClick} type="button">
        clear form
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 17):

You can clear the value in the input field like below.

```js
const handleClick= () => {
 inputRef.current.value = "";
 return "hello world"
}
```

and change `onClick` call in the button like below

```js
onClick={handleClick}
//or
onClick={()=> handleClick()}
```

If you want complete reset of a form having multiple inputs, you can follow the below approach. 
In below example, form will reset after submit

```js
const formRef = useRef();

const handleClick = () => { 
  formRef.current.reset();
}

render() {
  return (
    <form ref={formRef}>
      <input />
      <input />
      ...
      <input />
    </form>
  );
}
```

if you don't want to use Ref

```js
const handleSubmit = e => {
 e.preventDefault();
 e.target.reset();
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: If you see the last comment in question, he just wanted to reset value of the input field. To complete reset the form, user can use Ref in `<form ref={f_ref}>` element and reset it by using `f_ref.current.reset()`

Comment: I've updated the example.. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: yes, but your answer states to `reset the value...` this will be misleading to future users as you are not actually resetting - just clearing whatever is value is input - which would include any default. This is important when there is a default value.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it.. I'm updating my answer

Comment: Answers the question and is the 'more react way' to do this

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems, one you are passing a function that calls a function into your onClick handler -- which isn't needed. If you define the function before your render, you do not need to pass an anonymous function to the onClick handler.

```
// Before
<button onClick={()=> handleClick}>delete all</button>

// After
<button onClick={handleClick}>delete all</button>
```

The other problem is that your handleClick function calls reset, which is not a function on an input. To reset the value of the referenced input, you can set it to an empty string (or whatever you want the "default" value to be).

```
  const handleClick = e => {
   inputRef.current.value = "";
   return "hello world";
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

rest value in input

```js
import { useRef } from 'react'

const Test = () => {
  const testRef = useRef(null)
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={testRef} />
      <button onClick={() => inputSearch.current.value = ''}>×</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Test
```