# How can I clear the the inner text of a ref.current value, in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ref, form-control, create-ref

How can I access the inner text value property of a ref.current.

By console.log(loginField.current) I got:

```
<div class="some name">
   <input aria-invalid="false" id="login" placeholder="Email" type="text" class="other name" value="">
</div>
```

The way I set loginField, is:

```
  let loginField = React.createRef();
```

and

```
          <FormControl className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}>
            <StyledInput
              id={LOGIN}
              type="text"
              value={values.login}
              disableUnderline={true}
              placeholder="Email"
              ref={loginField}             // I set it here
              onFocus={handleFocus}
              error={fieldsErrors.loginError !== ''}
              onChange={handleChange(LOGIN)}
            />
          </FormControl>
```

I need to clear the inner input of this div from previous values. (set it to '')

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412963/how-to-reset-input-field-from-useref-in-react

Comment: thank you for answering, I tried loginField.current.reset(), but I get an error, saying that "loginField.current.reset is not a function". I also tried reset() in the references to the fields directly, but I also get an error

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you are using MUI which basically gives a wrapped component according to docs [here](https://material-ui.com/api/input/) and to pass refrence to input you ll have to pass a prop to comonent as

```
   ...
   inputRef={myref}
   ...
```

Comment: Hi @Fahad Tahir, I tried it all with no success. By doing console.log I found out that my ref value is something like "<div><input value="a value"></div>", it is html, not an object (I guess that is because I am using Material UI’s FormControl), and it is a div that encloses an input, and the input has a value. How do I get to that input to set its value? Clearing the states is not clearing the values when the page first renders. However, it works perfectly

Comment: can you share your StyledInput where you did styling

Comment: Try this
```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  min-width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 7px 10px;

`;
const StyledInput = styled.input`
  min-width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
`;

function Profile() {
  let inputRef = useRef()

  const handleClear = () => {
    console.log(inputRef.current.value)
    inputRef.current.value = ""
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <StyledInput ref={inputRef} ></StyledInput>
       <StyledButton onClick={handleClear} >clear</StyledButton>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I am not using styled components directly, I am using Material UI, and the way I define StyledInput is: "const StyledInput = withStyles({ root: { '&$focused': { borderColor: '#B3B3B3' }, '&$error': { borderColor: '#D33F49' }, … })(Input);", This “withStyles” is imported from '@material-ui/core/styles'

Comment: I didn't understand the definition you wrote

Comment: try inputRef={loginField} instead of ref=() as MUI automatically have a wrapper according to the docs https://material-ui.com/api/input/ to assign ref to the input inside pass inputRef as a parameter and it ll be assigned to input inside