# Unable to reset form

Tags: reactjs, forms, function, state

I have been trying allday to reset the file selection once the upload button has been pressed, it looks like I should be used a useRef to reset the value back to null however I can't seem to make it work..

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react"
import useUploader from "../hooks/Uploader"

function UploadPhotos() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState()
  const fname = useRef(null)
  const [uploadFiles] = useUploader(files)

  const filechangeHandler = (e) => {
    setFiles(e.target.files)
  }
  const submit = (e) => {
    ;(e) => {
      uploadFiles()
    },
      (fname.current.value = null)
  }

  return (
    <div className=" font-Montserrat text-md absolute flex h-[80%] w-full items-center justify-center gap-5">
      <form id="data_upload">
        <input type="file" multiple onChange={filechangeHandler} ref={fname} />
        <button onClick={submit}>click here to upload</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UploadPhotos
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `setFiles([])` after the `submit()` ?

Comment: You cannot do that because updating a ref won't cause a re-render in React, causing UI to stay staled. You'd better use a controlled form with `useState` instead of `useRef` so you can gain the ability to clear out the form.

Comment: Actually, `reset` is available on the `form` element, so can achieve what you want by using the `ref` on the `form` instead of `input`. See more details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62413386/4549166

Comment: @TaiweiTuan this works almost perfectly, however it doesn't deselect the files from a file select input..

Comment: @Brian yeah that's just the limitation of the `useRef` which is it doesn't cause a re-render. In this case you'd really want to consider controlled formed with `useState`. In a nutshell, see the conclusion of this article here https://designtechworld.medium.com/useref-vs-usestate-in-react-330539025245#7ad7

Answer (score 1):

a few things..

The submit function has an incorrect structure. You're using a comma , to separate two expressions, but the first expression is wrapped in an arrow function which is never invoked.

The useUploader hook is not defined in the code snippet. I'll assume it works correctly for the purpose of this answer.

The useState for files is initialized as undefined. It would be better to initialize it as null or an empty array.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import useUploader from "../hooks/Uploader"; 

function UploadPhotos() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState(null);
  const fileInputRef = useRef(null);
  const [uploadFiles] = useUploader(files);

  const fileChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setFiles(e.target.files);
  };

  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
    uploadFiles(); 
    setFiles(null); // Reset the files state
    if (fileInputRef.current) {
      fileInputRef.current.value = null; // Reset the file input
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="font-Montserrat text-md absolute flex h-[80%] w-full items-center justify-center gap-5">
      <form id="data_upload" onSubmit={submit}>
        <input type="file" multiple onChange={fileChangeHandler} ref={fileInputRef} />
        <button type="submit">Click here to upload</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UploadPhotos;
```

Hopefully this modified version swill reset the file input once the upload button has been pressed.

Changed the useState initialization for files to null.
Added e.preventDefault() to prevent the default form submission behaviour.
And the submit function is now the onSubmit handler for the form, and the button type is set to "submit" to trigger this.

Comment: This does work, however it causes the uploadFiles function to fire twice, when previousily it would upload correctly.

Comment: Oh, my apologies... it's because both the button click and the form submission triggering the submit function.

In your original code, you were using onClick on the button to handle the form submission. I used onSubmit. So, if you click the button, it could trigger both onClick and onSubmit, causing the function to fire twice.

To fix this, you can remove the onClick handler from the button and rely solely on the form's onSubmit to handle the upload and reset. That way, the function will only fire once when the form is submitted.