# clear(); method not working for React inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, protractor

Most of the application we are developing is made with Angular but we are slowly transitioning to rebuilding it in ReactJS. `clear()` still works perfectly on Angular inputs but does absolutely nothing on React inputs

I wrote a reusable function long ago:

```
const clearAndSendKeys = async (input, text) => {
    await input.clear();
    await input.sendKeys(text);
};
```

The above function works perfectly well on angular elements, but the `clear()` part does not have any effect on pages made with React.
I also tried not using the function and just go with

```
await input.clear();
await input.sendKeys(text);
```

doesn't work either.
I will paste one of the inputs and the method I'm using to locate it

```
<div widths="equal" class="required field">
    <label>
        "Address"
        ::after
    </label>
    <div class="ui input">
        <input name="address1" placeholder type="text" value="fake address">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Locator**:
`const addressInput = element(by.name('address1'));`

**UPDATE**
I could work around this by using the backspace key in a loop. It's not the ideal method but it works (the ideal method would be `clear()` to work

```
    this.clearInput = async (input) => {
        const inputValue = await input.getAttribute('value');
        const valueLength = await inputValue.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < valueLength; i++) {
            await input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
        };
    };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear and reset form input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922508/clear-and-reset-form-input-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could work around this by using the backspace key in a loop. It's not the ideal method but it works (the ideal method would be clear() to work

```
this.clearInput = async (input) => {
    const inputValue = await input.getAttribute('value');
    const valueLength = await inputValue.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < valueLength; i++) {
        await input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
    };
};
```

This is not the best solution but it does the job for now. Although I would love to know why the `clear()` method does not work in these react input components

Comment: Oh weird. I have no idea why this is not working. Some more info (in possibly figuring out why this is happening), Protractor element finder uses the direct implementation of `clear` from selenium-webdriver. The list of selenium-webdriver methods is https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/element.ts#L16-L20. The clear method applies input and textarea elements https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L2385-L2395.

Answer (score 2):

what if you try to [reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922508/clear-and-reset-form-input-fields) the input

```
let reset = async $elem => 
    browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].reset()', $elem.getWebElement());
```

Let me know if doesn't work

P.S.

Okay... I know what you'll see below is ugly and stupid... but it did the work for me for for the last year in all 16 apps I test

```
sendKeys: async ($element, keyCode = '') => {
        let size = await $element.getSize();
        let clickCoordinates = {
            x: Math.round(size.width - 3),
            y: Math.round(size.height / 2),
        };

        let value = await $element.getAttribute('value');
        for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            await $element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
        }
        await $element.clear();

        // see a pic below, for example of where I click
        await browser
            .actions()
            .mouseMove($element, clickCoordinates)
            .click()
            .perform();
        await $element.sendKeys('1');
        await $element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
        await $element.sendKeys(keyCode);
    },
```

[image]

Comment: If I try to execute that on the input I get `arguments[0].reset is not a function`. If I do it on the form as a whole it doesn't do anything

Comment: Updated with P.S. I didn't want to post it, but you made me lol

Comment: lol, I do have a similar method that uses `protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE` in a loop and it does work, I just don't get why `.clear()` won't work on these inputs